# What is the the maximum time for a user to return to Google for the visit to be flagged up as a bounce in GA?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads, bounce-rate, bounce

I know that Google measures bounce rates by how fast a user returns to the results page after clicking-through to a website. Roughly what is the maximum duration of the visit for the user to then return for it to be considered a bounce?

i.e. <5 seconds, <30 seconds?

I'm mainly interested as it appears a lot of users clicking through my PPC adverts (Adwords) are bouncing, despite my ads having a high quality score and the page's being entirely related to the adverts copy and at as best tied to what I think user's may be searching for from the key phrases I've selected so the high bounce rate (100% on some keywords) seems a bit strange.

If a bounce isn't determined by time, but simply whether a user returns to the SERP after visiting my site or not after any amount of time that would make more sense but the average duration of visit for my keywords with a 100% bounce rate in GA is 00:00:00, which suggests a user immediately returned to the SERPs, which again, is odd.

Is my GA data being skewed by https or anything like that?

Scratching my head here.

Answer (score 1):

Please read http://padicode.com/blog/analytics/the-real-bounce-rate/

Essentially, it boils down to this: `bounce rate [is] being the percent of traffic that stayed on your website for fewer than 10 seconds.`

`What you need to do is to fire up an event each time a user spends more than 10 seconds (or you can define your own standard) on the website. Just add the following line under the pageTracker._trackPageview();`

And the code:

```
setTimeout('pageTracker._trackEvent(\'NoBounce\', \'NoBounce\', \'Over 10 seconds\')',10000);
```

You can set your own bounce threshold using this method, and your data should adjust accordingly.

***All text in** `this type` **is quoted from article above.***